# Debian VM shows incorrect RAM size after reducing it in VMWare

Tags: debian, memory, vmware

I have a Linux VM running Debian 12.1. Initially, I allocated 16GB of RAM to it. However, I've since realized that I don't actually need that much memory, and 8GB should suffice. I powered down the virtual machine and adjusted the memory allocation in VMWare to 8GB. When I boot the Linux VM, I can confirm the new memory size by checking the "dmesg" output, which correctly displays the adjusted size.

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep memory
[    2.967853] vmwgfx 0000:00:0f.0: [drm] Legacy memory limits: VRAM = 8192 kB, FIFO = 256 kB, surface = 0 kB
[    2.967859] vmwgfx 0000:00:0f.0: [drm] Maximum display memory size is 8192 kiB
```

However, the old memory allocation values are still displayed in tools like "top," "free," and in the "/proc/meminfo" file.

```
$ free
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        16376480      477100    15924248         636      240124    15899380
Swap:         998396           0      998396

$ cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:       16376480 kB
MemFree:        15923996 kB
```

How can I resolve this inconsistency?

Comment: Those dmesg lines only concerns how much memory is on your (virtual) graphics card, `dmesg` usually doesn't report how much (ordinary) memory is in the machine. On a physical machine you can use `dmidecode` to see what memory is physically there, but I have no idea how that would behave in VMWare. My guess would be that you haven't actually reduced the amout of ordinary RAM available, but it's been years since I used VMWare so I can't remember what you could set (and they could have changed that anyway).

Comment: Good point, I checked twice and VMware shows 8GB on this VM

Answer (score 0):

After conducting some investigation, I discovered a "mem" parameter within Grub2.

```
$ sudo vim /etc/default/grub
...
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="mem=8192m"
...
$ sudo update-grub
```

Following the reboot, top/proc/meminfo/free display the accurate memory values.

Update: I want to express my gratitude to Chris Davies and Henrik – you were absolutely correct. I don't have direct control over this VM; I only have SSH access. The individual who manages it didn't correctly adjust the RAM size.

Comment: It might be better to remove that segment entirely and let the system determine the memory size dynamically

Comment: I agree, if I remove this I still see 16GB. But I checked VM configuration and it shows only 8GB?!

Comment: You've shut off the VM (from VMware's perspective) so that changes are definitely applied to the virtual hardware?

Comment: Thanks Chris. I reached the person who controls VMware, and it seems he did not finish configuration. So, now it works as expected! Thanks again! See my comment in my answer